# Laravel Blade Localization in if statement

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to create an if statement in a Laravel 5.2 blade template with the localization trans() function.

What I want to achieve is that if the content I am calling is 'true' I would like to show an image - else just print '-' to the website.

The code so far looks like this:

```
    <div class="table-cell">
      @if (trans('content.offer.text') == 'true')
        <img src="../images/tick.png" class="img-responsive" />
      @else
        -
    </div>
```

Informatin to the code: The localization file exists, also the entry exists and I wrote it correctly - if I just echo it, it says true on the website. The content of the value is 'true' or 'false':

```
    'text' => 'true',
```

However, this is giving me a "parse error" message without much useful information (it literally just says: "Fatal Error - parse error").

**My question:** How do I write this if statement with the localization function trans() correctly?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, me dumdum... I didn't realise that @if also needs an @endif if there is an @else after the @if.... Sorry to bother all the readers.